# Temporary expose Hashicorp Vault API on AKS Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure-aks, hashicorp-vault, azure-load-balancer

I have installed Hashicorp Vault on Azure Kubernetes Service, AKS, for the first time. I have no experience with Vault. This is more a AKS question anyway.
Using Helm, the deployed Vault has exposed vault-ui service using a LoadBalancer and an external IP on port 20001, which is OK.
Vault will be used in other Kubernetes namespaces of the same cluster so I don't need main vault port (8200) exposed to outside, but I need to perform some actions using a local docker in my notebook, so I would like to very temporary expose port 8200 using the same External-IP address that has been created for Vault-UI (and not using a new LoadBalancer with a new IP)

What az or kubectl commands should I use to expose that vault service in the loadbalancer at 8200 port that can easily be also removed keeping only vault-ui exposed?